# System.ArgumentException ao utilizar MySQL com Entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

Eu instalei o MySQL connector no ambiente, instalei as referências do MySQL através do Nuget package. Quando inicio o sistema e tento fazer uma inserção no banco de dados, o seguinte erro aparece:

> The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySQL Data Provider' is
> either not registered in the machine or application config file, or
> could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Não foi possível localizar o Provedor de Dados .Net Framework solicitado.
> Talvez ele não esteja instalado.

ConnectionString:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="MySQL Data Provider" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=bananasfit;Uid=root; " />
```

Provider

```
<DbProviderFactories>
      <clear/>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
```

O que pode estar ocasionando este erro?

Answer (score 3):

Faltou registrar o provider junto com o Entity Framework:

```
<entityFramework>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
              type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Aliás, o `invariantName` precisa ser igual ao tipo implementado na biblioteca:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=bananasfit;Uid=root; " />
```